# create app on Jhipster using java7?

Tags: java, jhipster

I am trying to use jhipster, so far Ive seen how it works on java8, I even found an example repo with java7 that is certainly java 8 (https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-java7).

I was wondering if there is any way I can generate an app to run with java7? I know is deprecated from jhipster but seems like if I can run jhipster v 1.7.0 I could do it, any idea how?

So far this is what jhipster -help shows

```
C:\Users\user>jhipster -help

  Usage: jhipster [command] [options]


  Commands:

    app                       Create a new JHipster application based on the selected options
    aws                       Deploy the current application to Amazon Web Services
    ci-cd                     Create pipeline scripts for popular Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment tools
    client                    Create a new JHipster client-side application based on the selected options
    cloudfoundry              Generate a `deploy/cloudfoundry` folder with a specific manifest.yml to deploy to Cloud Foundry
    docker-compose            Create all required Docker deployment configuration for the selected applications
    entity [name]             Create a new JHipster entity: JPA entity, Spring server-side components and Angular client-side components
    export-jdl [jdlFile]      Create a JDL file from the existing entities
    heroku                    Deploy the current application to Heroku
    import-jdl [jdlFiles...]  Create entities from the JDL file passed in argument
    info                      Display information about your current project and system
    kubernetes                Deploy the current application to Kubernetes
    languages [languages...]  Select languages from a list of available languages. The i18n files will be copied to the /webapp/i18n folder
    openshift                 Deploy the current application to OpenShift
    rancher-compose           Deploy the current application to Rancher
    server                    Create a new JHipster server-side application
    service [name]            Create a new Spring service bean
    upgrade                   Upgrade the JHipster version, and upgrade the generated application
    completion                Print command completion script

  Options:

    -h, --help     output usage information
    -d, --debug    enable debugger
    -V, --version  output the version number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to a 2 years old project sample. Current version of JHipster 4.x requires JDK 8, there's no way to generate a project compatible with JDK 7 with it.

The only solution would be to install an obsolete version of JHipster like 2.22.0 which is the one used to generate this JDK 7 sample project:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster@2.22.0
```

then follow instructions of this version's documentation: http://www.jhipster.tech/documentation-archive/v2.22.0/